# Purpose of bytes type in GRPC?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

Can anyone explain in detail what is the purpose of using bytes in grpc? or when we can used bytes in grpc? or in which scenario we can used bytes data type? any one can give example on it?

Comment: Like images and compressed data, probably.

Comment: Hello, I've been using byte to serialise/deserialise some closed class that I cant mark as ProtoContract, exemple TimeZoneInfo, if I dont do that I cannot serialize it.